# Problem with WhenEvent in solving a PDE with NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, event-detection

I have problem with my PDE. The problem is as bellow:

[image]
I used "WhenEvent" operator to solve it. The code is:

```
a = 255
b = 2.5
heat1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], 
  t] - (0.0000001 D[u[t, x], x, x] + b*Exp[a *x]) == 
NeumannValue[0, True] + NeumannValue[-7 (u[t, x] - 25), x == .05],
u[0, x] == 25, 
WhenEvent[
u[t, x] > 250, {a = 0.01*a, b = .2 b, "RestartIntegration"}]}, 
u, {t, 0, 600}, {x, 0, .05}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
  "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.001}}}}]
pa = Plot[Evaluate[heat1[t, 0.05]], {t, 0, 600}, PlotRange -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {t, "T(.05,t)"}]
```

After running this code, I got the following errors.

```
" NDSolveValue::nbnum1: The function value        InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,0.05}},{5,4225,0,{101},{3},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{<<1>>},{25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,<<15>>,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,25.,<<51>>},{Automatic}][x]>250 is not True or False when the arguments are {0.,{<<1>>},{2.50058,3.22634,4.16337,5.37266,6.93321,8.94703,11.5458,14.8994,<<36>>,186525.,240704.,310619.,400841.,517266.,667489.,<<51>>}}. >>
General::stop: Further output of NDSolveValue::nbnum1 will be suppressed during this calculation. >> "
```

How can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: At a given time, `u[t, x]` is an array of values.  Which do you wish to compare with 250?  Perhaps, the largest value?

Comment: @bbgodfrey that you for your comment. As you said, at a given time, u[t, x], is an array of values. I want to check all of them and see if this value is higher than 250 or not. if it is lower that value, the solution is OK. But if it is higher than 250, it should be solved based on the corrections that mentioned. Now how can I do this?

Comment: I have fixed the coding problems by defining a and b as discrete variables, and making related changes. However, your coded boundary condition at x == 0.05 is not the same as your boundary condition written in LaTex and is causing severe difficulties.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Can you please send the code here? Which part of the  boundary condition is not true?

Comment: The LaTex boundary condition involves a temporal derivative, but the coded boundary condition involves a spatial derivative.  Moreover, the spatial derivative for `x` just less than `.05` is positive and large, but the coded boundary condition at `x == 0.5` has a negative and large spatial derivative.  This incompatibility causes rapid variation in `u` near `x == 0.5`.

Comment: In the latex formulation `f(x,u)` is a discontinuous function of `x` at any `t`, because `u` is a function of `x`. Is that what you intend? Your `WhenEvent` appears to be attempting  switch  `a,b` for all `x` based on some critera. Can you clarify when you intend.

Comment: @bbgodfrey That is true, it was my mistake. I edited the LaTex boundary condition. Is it OK now?

Comment: @george2079 The question is based on the latex formulation. I think I did a mistake in my code. consider a system that the governing equation for that system is given in latex formulation, the heterogeneous term is not the same for all u(x,t), if u become more than 250, the heterogeneous term will be changed according to latex formulation.

Comment: I think you should explicitly put `f[x,u[t,x]]` in the latex formulation to make it clear if that's what you mean.

Comment: @george2079 Thank you for your quick response, I edited the latex formulation. Now is it possible to solve it with a code that I wrote?

Comment: You should not delete your code. Please restore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following illustrates how to use `WhenEvent`, but I had to change the `NeumannValue` at `x == 0.05` to produce a well-behaved solution.

```
tmax = .01;
heat1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] - (0.0000001 D[u[t, x], x, x] + b[t]*Exp[a[t] *x]) == 
    NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[0 , x == 1/20],
    u[0, x] == 25, a[0] == 255 , b[0] == 2.5,
    WhenEvent[u[t, 1/20] > 250, {a[t] -> 0.01*a[t], b[t] -> .2 b[t]}]}, 
    {u, a, b}, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1/20}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.001}}}},
    DiscreteVariables -> {a, b}];
Plot[Evaluate[heat1[[1]][t, 1/20]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, "T(.05,t)"}]
LogPlot[heat1[[2]][t], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, "a"}]
```

[image]

[image]

The second plot, added for convenience, shows the history of `a`.

The **revised question** has a rather different answer.

```
tmax = .001;
heat2 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 0.0000001 D[u[t, x], x, x] + 
    Piecewise[{{2.5 Exp[255 x], u[t, x] < 250}}, .5 Exp[2.55 x]] , 
    u[0, x] == 25, (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, 
    (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1/20) == 7 (u[t, 1/20] - 25)}, 
     u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1/20}];
Plot[heat2[t, 1/20], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, "T(.05,t)"}]
```

[image]

Perhaps more illustrative is

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[heat2[t, x]], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1/20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note that the "FiniteElement" `Method` has been deleted, because it is incompatible as implemented in Mathematica 11.0.1 with the use of `Piecewise`, `If`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I edited my latex, can you please check it and edit your answer based on that? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer, just one more question, I want to know that, which book or tutorial is good for me for more practicing and learning Mathematica?

Comment: Try [An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/?source=nav), and on this site [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) and [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users).  Also, take the introductory [tour] now.  Best wishes.